# Creating Android Expansion file

Tags: android, gradle

Is it possible to create an android expansion file using Gradle ? Are there any other builder for creating expansion files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1/** define somewhere in your app build gradle script version code, package name:

```
def lVersionCode   = 20
def lApplicationId = 'com.xxx.android.app'
```

**2/** select a place to put the files that will be in your expansion file. In my case i created this one:

ExpansionFiles/src

**3/** then include in your app build gradle script the following code:

```
def destFile = new StringBuilder().append( 'main.' )
        .append( lVersionCode )
        .append( '.' )
        .append( lApplicationId )
        .append( '.zip' )
        .toString()

task expansionFileZip(type: Zip) {
    from('../../ExpansionFile/src') // Replace with your expansion file source
    include '*.mp3' // Replace with the extension of the files
    archiveName destFile // note that this specifies path *in* the archive
    destinationDir file('build/outputs/apk') // directory that you want your archive to be placed in
}
```

**4/** call gradle expansionFileZip in the same folder where your build gradle file is.